# meshmixer Alternative

Tags: 3d

we recently started 3d scanning orthopedic parts at work and so far I have used Meshmixer for simple operations like mesh clean up, making watertight meshes, cuts, wall offsets and simple manipulations of parts of the mesh.
Based on the tools Meshmixer is 90% there, but it hasn't been updated since 2017 and the graphic bugs make it more and more unusable.

I have looked for alternatives, but googling "meshmixer alternatives" brings up 3d printing slicers, 3d scanning apps, cad modelling software and other unrelated software. The closest would be meshlab, but this one is mostly only for manipulating the hole mesh and not modifying parts of it.

Has anyone come across a similar tool like meshmixer?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you'll find [Meshlab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeshLab) will do as you require when combined with other programs. I think it's the "other programs" aspect of the following blog tutorial which makes Meshlab viable.

In the process of exploring scanning options, I've discovered a number of methods using various sources (phone, camera, dedicated hardware) and a number of those methods involve using Meshlab.

Prusa Printers has a blog [entry](https://blog.prusaprinters.org/photogrammetry-3d-scanning-just-phone-camera_7811/) which specifically references Meshlab as the best option (for this particular tutorial) in performing photogrammetry.

From that page:

Creating mesh from point cloud data

- Open Meshlab, Select File – Import Mesh and choose the fused.ply
  file
- You’ll be presented with the captured scene made from 3D points
- Pick the Select vertexes tool from the main toolbar (top) and use it
  to select all points you wish to delete
- The tool works as a box selection, hold down the left mouse button
  to create a selection
- You can hold Ctrl to add more vertexes to already selected ones
- Click on the Delete vertices button in the main toolbar. Selected
  vertices will disappear
- Repeat steps 3-4 until you’re left with just the points you want to
  use for creating the mesh of the scanned object
- Select Filters – Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction –
  Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction
  The Reconstruction Depth has a major effect on the final result. Values between 13-15 usually look the best and take a reasonable time to compute
  Other settings usually work best at default values, but feel free to experiment with them
- Hit Apply to create a Mesh
- The edges of your model will usually end as a weird shape or even curl up and create a huge blob.
- Similarly to selecting and deleting vertices, you can do the same
  with triangles using the Select in triangular region and Delete
  faces tools from the main toolbar

End of sequence from blog post.

There are previous and succeeding steps involving other free software, but this provides and indication of the effort involved in converting a mesh to a model.

There are other resources involving Meshlab, as a search returns multiple links.

Comment: Yes meshlab is the right direction, but I particularly like meshmixer "paint for 3d approach" its simple and would work fine exept for the bucks. 
Also there are someone also many more programms similar to meshlab for wholesale mesh creation, but somehow not for manipulation. 
I guess blender would be the next thing to try, but thats also a whole other can of worms